# Same modules on one page in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, module

I am using JA Cloris template which is a one page template for joomla 2.5. I have implemented a module in a section of the page. Is it possible to implement the same module in different position of the same page. If so please help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the same module twice on the page, just add another copy of the module to the Module Manager and place it in a different module position. Most modules can be used as many times as you want on the same or different pages by just adding another copy in the Module Manager.

If you need to style the module differently (example: One is a wide wide horizontal module position vs. a vertical or square sidebar position), add a Module Class Suffix. That will allow you to add CSS styling to a module without affecting the other copies of it on the page.